# Ordered array of strings - worst case?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Would **O(log n)** be the worst case search time limited to an ordered array of strings of length n?

I just did a test today and i wondering if i'm right or wrong, selecting that out these...

- O(n)
- O(log n)
- O(n/2)
- O(√n)

**EDIT:** I edited this question to make things clearer.

Comment: What does `"for an ordered array of strings"` mean? did you mean "sorting"? Also: what is `n`? The number of strings? What is the length of each string? Is it constant?

Comment: Did you mean sorting or searching?

Comment: as a note, squareroots almost never come up in big O notations.  I've only seen it twice in my six years.

Answer (score 0):

Searching a string in a *sorted* array of strings would be `O(|S| * logn)` where `|S|` is the average length of a string, and `n` is the number of strings, using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), since it has `O(logn)` compare ops, and each compare is `O(|S|)` (It has to read the string...)

If you regard the length of the strings as constants - it is `O(logn)`. This assumption is generally not taken when talking about strings.

Note that there are other data structures - such as [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), that allows better complexity. Trie allows `O(|S|)` search for each string in the collection.

P.S.

Mathematically speaking, since big O notation is an upper bound, and not a tight bound - **all of the answers are correct**<sup>1</sup> for binary search, it is `O(n)`, `O(n/2)` , `O(logn)`, `O(sqrt(n))`, since all of them provide assymptotic upper bound for binary search.

---

(1) assuming binary search and all strings have bounded length, so each compare op is `O(1)`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: My answer explicitly states "binary search". Also, I just added the fact that for binary search - all answers are correct, since big O gives asympotic upper bound, and not a tight one.

Comment: @MrTeeth: I think the question as it is now, is badly formatted, and thus cannot be answered. If we take the assumption that each string is of bounded length, and we use binary search - then all answers are correct. **If the question in your test is indeed the same as this question,then all answers should be accepted.**

Answer (score 0):

[Sequential Search:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search)

Best:O(n) Worst:O(n)

[Binary Search:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Best:O(1) Worst:O(log n)

Comment: You should mention you regard each string compare as `O(1)`. This assumption is *usually* not a good practice when talking about strings.

Comment: best casee for a sequential sort isn't O(n) if the best case binary search is O(1)